# Javascript 2d Array: going out of bounds problem

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a weird-looking problem.
I have a "2d array", which stores x-y details in the form of 0's and 1's. I am checking if there is a 0 in any "direction" on a given coordinate.
This means that if I'm at 0-5 for example, it goes out of bounds.

This should give an error on all checks that are going out of bounds. But it only gives it on the outer "x array", not the inner "y arrays"....

```
//x = 0, y = 0
if(visitedGrid[x][y-2] != undefined && visitedGrid[x][y-2] == 0){//here its fine
  unvisitedDirections[0] = 0;
}

if(visitedGrid[x-2][y] != undefined && visitedGrid[x-2][y] == 0){//here it gives an error
  unvisitedDirections[3] = 0;
}
```

How can I fix this, so that no error appears?
I really don't know what to do with this one...

Comment: `Array.isArray(visitedGrid[x-2]) && visitedGrid[x-2][y] == 0`

Comment: Oh wow.... This shows how newb I am.... totally forgot isArray.... Thx @JaromandaX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if *`visitedGrid[x-2]`* is an array, and then check if `visitedGrid[x-2][y] == 0`. Checking if it is an array is easy, just use Array.isArray. So that would simply be:

```
if(Array.isArray(visitedGrid[x-2]) && visitedGrid[x-2][y] == 0){//here it doesn't gives an error
  unvisitedDirections[3] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work. Array.isArray() was the one I got working, thanks to Jaromanda X's comment on the question :) Still thx for suggesting, I appreciate it!